# Service workers checking import script for byte sized difference

Tags: service-worker

I have been checking a lot of threads on this topic , and can't seem to find a clear answer to this .

Question :

***Do service workers check imported scripts for byte size difference, and trigger update of SW if there is difference.***

In GitHub issues I went through :

- [Add web SDK API for service worker to be updated manually](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/113)
- [Consider relying on eTags (or other headers) for service worker dependencies to check for updates](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/839#issuecomment-236256162)

And also followed up with these :

- [Jake Archibald's Service worker meeting notes](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/service-worker-meeting-notes/)
- [Service worker: importScripts never updates scripts](http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2016/07/service-worker-importscripts-never-updates-scripts/)

Most of the articles are from 2016/17 and they are saying this should be implemented. On GitHub theres even a mention that work on this has started, but nothing more, no clear status on this or maybe I'm just missing it ?

**Any info on this would be helpful.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/fresher-sw), starting in version 68, chrome will ignore HTTP cache when requesting updates to the service worker script. Requests for **importScripts will still go via the HTTP cache. But this is just the default—a new registration option, updateViaCache is available** that offers control over this behavior.

Example of updateViaCache option:

`if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', {
    updateViaCache: 'none'
  });
}`

> When set to 'none', the HTTP cache will not be consulted when making requests for either the top-level /service-worker.js or for any imported scripted, such as the hypothetical path/to/import.js.

Comment: First, thank you for help. `updateViaCache`  so just to check with you is this available now or it's coming with chrome version 68 ? And if i set it to 'none' this should make my service worker to update if importScript changes ?

Comment: @SergejV according to the docs it's an upcoming feature for Chrome 68, from my understanding setting `updateViaCache` to 'none' browser will check importedScripts as well.

Comment: Yea , thats what I was looking for , thank you once again .

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the filesize difference in the SW file itself.  If you would look at this [SW example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/prefetch/service-worker.js) at line 31, the variable `CACHE_VERSION` gets updated everytime there is an update.  This will enable the browser to dump the old one and get a new version from the server.

Comment: The thing is that my SW file now has only one line and that is importScript(link to cdn). I'm only using it for push notifications and nothing else, also I don't want my customers to have to update sw file manually everytime there is an update hence the use of importScript. Problem is that all the users that already have SW installed , are not getting updates and are stuck with old SW .